# Changing the default authentication methods in the AWS go SDK v2

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, sdk, aws-sdk

By default, the golang AWS SDK v2 will use the following chain to determine credentials:

- environment variables
- shared config
- ECS task role (if ECS task)
- EC2 instance profile (if running on EC2)

I have a situation where I need to configure the SDK to ignore the first two (specifically environment variables)... we have a CI workflow where it's possible for AWS environment variables to be set for testing reasons, but we have a service for automating change requests in our change tracking system that should ONLY ever use ECS or EC2 credentials for authentication. The tooling we're using for accessing the change requests is written in go.

The v1 SDK actually had a `NewChainCredentials` function for creating a new chain, but that is gone in v2. Reading the code seems to indicate it's POSSIBLE to create a new credentials chain, but I haven't been able to figure out how to replace the default chain with just the ECS and EC2 providers.

Has anybody done this? Searching through Google and GitHub hasn't turned up anything that looks like what I want - mostly I find out to replace the default chain with a custom provider or add a new provider to the chain, but trying to use those methods to replace the default chain with the one I want have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but some of the specific implementation details on what kind of process to use to get credentials will have to be brought up into your code (that sucks). There are numerous amount of processes that the sdk defines in github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/credentials and sub directories.

You can get a sense of default credential chain [here](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2@4c206e10cec7783dbb2bdcc9d2bd43150afc30e1/-/blob/config/resolve_credentials.go?L111:6&popover=pinned)

Example of EC2 and ECS credential chain only:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/credentials/ec2rolecreds"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/credentials/endpointcreds"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
)

const (
    ecsContainerEndpoint = "http://169.254.170.2"
)

func ecsContainerURI(path string) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s%s", ecsContainerEndpoint, path)
}

func main() {
    os.Setenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY", "TEST")
    os.Setenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID", "TEST")
    // ECS credentials are read from an endpoint that is passed through
    // environment variables
    // os.Setenv("AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI", "/v2")

    var provider aws.CredentialsProvider
    envConfig, _ := config.NewEnvConfig()
    switch {
    case len(envConfig.ContainerCredentialsRelativePath) != 0:
        provider = endpointcreds.New(ecsContainerURI(envConfig.ContainerCredentialsRelativePath), func(options *endpointcreds.Options) {
            options.AuthorizationToken = envConfig.ContainerAuthorizationToken
            options.HTTPClient = &http.Client{
                Timeout: 1,
            }
        })
    default:
        provider = ec2rolecreds.New()
    }

    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(), config.WithRegion("us-west-2"),
        config.WithCredentialsProvider(aws.NewCredentialsCache(provider)))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to load SDK config, %v", err)
    }
    r, cerr := cfg.Credentials.Retrieve(context.TODO())
    fmt.Printf("%#v\nError: %#v", r, cerr)
}
```

As you can see I explicitly set AWS Environment Credentials that would normally be read by the default configuration, but since we are providing an our own cred provider they get ignored.

```golang
// we get no valid credentials since I am neither on Ec2 or ECS
aws.Credentials{AccessKeyID:"", SecretAccessKey:"", SessionToken:"", Source:"", CanExpire:false, Expires:time.Date(1, time.January, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)}
Error:&fmt.wrapError{msg:"failed to refresh cached credentials, no EC2 IMDS role found, operation error ec2imds: GetMetadata, request canceled, context deadline exceeded", err:(*fmt.wrapError)(0x140000a2240)}
```